# Buttons in the email settings pages look wrong

Tags: bug, design, css

On **[Edit Email Settings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current)**, the save button has illegibly colored text:

> [image]
>
> (I deleted my email from this field just for the screenshot. It looked like that even when I had one entered.)

The same happens on the **[Newsletters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/email/newsletters/current)** settings page:

> [image]

Buttons should look like this instead:

> [image]

Comment: It appears to be a mistake in how the CSS properties cascade: the right properties are loaded, but another set of properties particular to that page are overriding the site-default button text colour and border colour. (A quick look isn't enough to untangle the sheets though, and it might be generated CSS anyway…)